# Restore Files from previous Windows File History

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history

I downgraded my Windows yesterday from 11 to 10 (format C and reinstall). Then I tried to restore the Files from the File History.

So I opened the File History settings in control panel and selected the hard disk where I stored the file history before. It showed me the checkbox labeld "I want to use a previous backup on this File History device and selected my previous backup.

The File History still showed "File history is currently turned off", the control panel shows "File Hisotry is on" and the event viewer is showing "Unable to start a backup cycle for configuration ..."

I already have the feeling I should have made a backup of the configuration folder. Because it overwrote the config1 and config2 in the FileHistory folder on the backup drive.

Is there a tool that reads the edb file (no exchange database viewer) and can restore the data without having to rename 1000 of files? Otherwise I need a script that at least fixes the file names...

Comment: When you downgraded your system it’s very likely you cleared or otherwise wiped the previous versions for the file or most likely case they never existed in the first place. Was this installation of Windows 11, upgraded from 10, then downgraded to the original install or was the original installation Windows 11 and you installed a fresh install of Windows 10. This is important information since you cannot keep your files and downgrade your build of Windows to a lower build otherwise.Editing your question to clarify this information would be helpful.We probably won’t be able to provide a script

Comment: I upgraded long time ago and had to wipe the system partition before a fresh installation of win 10

Comment: So can you [edit] your question to reflect that fact? If you downgraded from Windows 11 to Windows 10, in reality, you wiped your Windows 11 installation and installed Windows 10. So it's not shocking or unexpected for File History to indicate it's disabled or there is no history for the drive (because there isn't). Why do you expect the File History from the Windows 11 installation to exist on the fresh Windows 10 installation? I have never heard of just pointing to a HDD from one installation and expecting FH to work.

Comment: I have the FH on a second hard drive. The files are still there (18 GB at least). When you select a hard drive it shows that this hard drive was used for FH before and it asks if want to use this backup. I thought I wrote that..

Comment: Yes; But why do you think you would be able to transfer your FH from Windows 11 to a Windows 10 instance? While Microsoft has not specifically made note of any changes to FH it's not out of the question that changes might exist between Windows 10 and Windows 11 with regards to FH.

Comment: WDYM? There is a backup of files and an .edb database file with metadata. Why should another instance of the same software not be able to restore the data? In settings you gind that under backup - isn't a backup something you can restore? What is a backup when you can't restore it after some malware destroyed your OS and you reinstall the OS?

Comment: File History shouldn't be considered a backup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140035/discussion-between-iras-and-ramhound).